# SSH authentication issues with Guacamole and Tomcat9 on Debian Bullseye

Tags: linux, ssh, tomcat

I have guacamole and tomcat9 installed on my Debian Bullseye.

RDP Connections work without any Problem, SSH doesn't work at all. I am trying to connect with a Private Key.

I got this from my Syslog:

```
Apr 26 10:05:00 guacamole guacd[1006]: Creating new client for protocol "ssh"
Apr 26 10:05:00 guacamole guacd[1006]: Connection ID is "$30cf72eb-1e83-4df1-aa02-c0f70a4cb496"
Apr 26 10:05:00 guacamole guacd[1595]: User "@45b89ce0-22ed-41c0-aa69-478dafa5af34" joined connection "$30cf72eb-1e83-4df1-aa02-c0f70a4cb496" (1 users now present)
Apr 26 10:05:00 guacamole guacd[1595]: Auth key successfully imported.
Apr 26 10:05:00 guacamole guacd[1595]: No known host keys provided, host identity will not be verified.
Apr 26 10:05:00 guacamole guacd[1595]: Public key authentication failed: Unable to extract public key from private key.
Apr 26 10:05:00 guacamole guacd[1595]: User "@45b89ce0-22ed-41c0-aa69-478dafa5af34" disconnected (0 users remain)
Apr 26 10:05:00 guacamole guacd[1595]: Last user of connection "$30cf72eb-1e83-4df1-aa02-c0f70a4cb496" disconnected
Apr 26 10:05:00 guacamole guacd[1006]: Connection "$30cf72eb-1e83-4df1-aa02-c0f70a4cb496" removed.
```

When I try to connect with user and password (without private key) I get this output from my Syslog:

```
Apr 26 10:17:35 guacamole guacd[1006]: Creating new client for protocol "ssh"
Apr 26 10:17:35 guacamole guacd[1006]: Connection ID is "$ba07d3a9-9ee4-4402-adab-ac17139dc91c"
Apr 26 10:17:35 guacamole guacd[1674]: User "@e52ec579-82dd-4574-9c60-dfed6c75e456" joined connection "$ba07d3a9-9ee4-4402-adab-ac17139dc91c" (1 users now present)
Apr 26 10:17:35 guacamole guacd[1674]: No known host keys provided, host identity will not be verified.
Apr 26 10:17:38 guacamole guacd[1674]: Password authentication failed: Authentication failed (username/password)
Apr 26 10:17:38 guacamole guacd[1674]: User "@e52ec579-82dd-4574-9c60-dfed6c75e456" disconnected (0 users remain)
Apr 26 10:17:38 guacamole guacd[1674]: Last user of connection "$ba07d3a9-9ee4-4402-adab-ac17139dc91c" disconnected
Apr 26 10:17:38 guacamole guacd[1006]: Connection "$ba07d3a9-9ee4-4402-adab-ac17139dc91c" removed.
```

I am still a newbie to Linux, so I don't know what I can do to fix this at all.